# Objectify List<Ref<T>> not serialized by Google App Engine endpoints

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, objectify, endpoints

Hi have two related Entities: Customers and Cars. Each Customer can own several Cars

This is a summarized view of the entities:

```
public class Customer 
{
    //Inner classes for partial loads
    public static class NoCars{}

    @Id protected String id;
    private String fullName;
    @Load(unless=NoCars.class) private List<Ref<Car>> cars;
}

public class Car
{
    @Id private Long id;
    private String makeAndModel;
    private String plateNumber;
}
```

And this is a method that retrieves a Customer from datastore **and all the Cars** he owns:

```
public Customer getCustomer(@Named("id") String customerId)
{
    Customer customer =  ofy().load().type(Customer.class).id(customerId).now();
    if (customer==null)
        throw new NotFoundException("customer not found");
    else
        return customer;
}
```

endpoints.sh cannot implement this, as the type **`List <Ref<Car>>`** included in the return type *Customer* is not supported, but I found this funny workaround:

I created the class *CustomerPOJO*

```
public class CustomerPOJO
{
    private String fullName;
}
```

and modified the class *`Customer`* to extend from it

```
public class Customer extends CustomerPOJO
{
    //Inner classes for partial loads
    public static class NoCars{}

    @Id protected String id;
    @Load(unless=NoCars.class) private List<Ref<Car>> cars = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and the getter method to be:

```
public CustomerPOJO getCustomer(@Named("id") String customerId)
{
    Customer customer =  ofy().load().type(Customer.class).id(customerId).now();
    if (customer==null)
        throw new NotFoundException("customer not found");
    else
        return customer;
}
```

Note that the method declares *`CustomerPOJO`* as return type, but it actually returns a "full" *`Customer`*!!!

**This works in AppEngine 1.8.0 + Objectify 4.0 RC2**. It gets the customer data and all the cars he owns with their properties (*`makeAndModel`* and *`plateNumber`*) in a single call.

The issue came after upgrading to 1.8.9. endpoints.sh still works, as the return type is fully compatible, but i get an exception at runtime, when parsing the Customer objecto to JSON.

> java.io.IOException:
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   entity.Customer["cars"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ref.LiveRef["key"]->com.googlecode.objectify.Key["root"])

**Any other workaround that works in 1.8.9? Is @ApiTransformer the only choice?**

Answer (score 3):

The solution was pretty simple... Just hide the Ref field. It does now provide any value to the API consumer and it just create trouble to the parser:

I replaced the `List<Ref<Car>>` getter and setter by:

```
public List<Car> getCars()
{
    List<Car> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Ref<Car>> it = cars.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        ret.add(it.next().getValue());
    return ret;
}

public void setCars(List<Car> newCars)
{
    Iterator<Car> it = newCars.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        addCar(it.next());
}
```

That's all